# In Python, how can I identify clusters of overlapping circles?

Tags: python, graphics, 2d, cluster-analysis

By clusters, I mean groups of linked overlapping circles. This image probably gives a better idea of what I'm trying to find:

[image]

In my data, circles are represented by their centerpoint coordinates. I have already done collision detection to produce a list of paired centered points representing the overlaps:

```
pts = [(-2,2), (-2,2), (0,0), (2,1), (6,2), (7,1)]

overlaps = [
    (pts[0], pts[1]),
    (pts[0], pts[2]),
    (pts[1], pts[2]),
    (pts[2], pts[3]),
    (pts[4], pts[5]),
]
```

This is the expected result:

```
expected_clusters = [
    ((-2,2), (-2,2), (0,0), (2,1)),
    ((6,2), (7,1))
]
```

In practice, the datasets I will be working with will be about this size so I'll probably never need to scale it up. But that's not to say I wouldn't favor a more optimal solution.

I've come up with my own naive solution, which I'll post as an answer. But I'd be interested in seeing other solutions.

Comment: Consider using networkx (http://networkx.github.com/) to represent your overlaps as a graph.  Then you can use the connnected_components function (http://networkx.github.com/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected.connected_components.html#networkx.algorithms.components.connected.connected_components)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're doing isn't really cluster analysis, it's [connected component](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29) analysis.  Cluster analysis would be taking a whole bunch of individual points and trying to discover the circles.  But it may be of interest to you that the combination of assigning points into initial neighborhoods and clustering based reachability through overlapping neighborhoods is the heart of the [DBSCAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN) idea and its [density-based clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis#Density-based_clustering) variants.

In any case, since you're starting with the circles, once you've done the collision detection, what you're calling your overlaps list is the adjacency list, and what you're calling the clusters are the connected components.  The algorithm is fairly straightforward:

1. Create a list `L` of all nodes.
2. Create an empty list of connected components `Cs`
3. While `L` is not empty:

   1. Pick an arbitrary node `N`
   2. Create a connected component list `C`, initialized with `N`
   3. Do a breadth-first or depth-first traversal using your adjacency list adding each node you encounter to `C`
   4. Append `C` to `Cs`
   5. Remove all nodes in `C` from `L`

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the terminology. That's always a big help.

Answer (score 1):

Edited original response in favor of [acjohnson55's algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14607978/1093087):

```
center_pts = [(-2,2), (-2,2), (0,0), (2,1), (6,2), (7,1)]

overlapping_circle_pts = [
    (center_pts[0], center_pts[1]),
    (center_pts[0], center_pts[2]),
    (center_pts[1], center_pts[2]),
    (center_pts[2], center_pts[3]),
    (center_pts[4], center_pts[5]),
]

expected_solution = [
    [(-2,2), (-2,2), (0,0), (2,1)],
    [(6,2), (7,1)]
]


def cluster_overlaps(nodes, adjacency_list):
    clusters = []
    nodes = list(nodes)  # make sure we're mutating a copy

    while len(nodes):
        node = nodes[0]
        path = dfs(node, adjacency_list, nodes)

        # append path to connected_nodes
        clusters.append(path)

        # remove all nodes from
        for pt in path:
            nodes.remove(pt)

    return clusters


def dfs(start, adjacency_list, nodes):
    """ref: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576723/"""
    path = []
    q = [start]

    while q:
        node = q.pop(0)

        # cycle detection
        if path.count(node) >= nodes.count(node):
            continue

        path = path + [node]

        # get next nodes
        next_nodes = [p2 for p1,p2 in adjacency_list if p1 == node]
        q = next_nodes + q

    return path

print cluster_overlaps(center_pts, overlapping_circle_pts)
```

Comment: Since you're doing a lot of removals from `nodes` and inclusion tests in `adjacency_list`, you'd be better off using `set` instances for each of them, I think. This does require hashable values, but fortunately tuples (of numbers) are hashable. Also, a `deque` from the `collections` module would be a more efficient data structure to implement a queue in your `dfs` function (popping and extending are much faster as a `deque` is implemented as a sort of linked list, rather than an array).